# Open images from a folder one by one using python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hi all I need to open images from a folder one by one do some processing on images and save them back to other folder. I am doing this using following sample code.

```
path1 = path of folder of images    
path2 = path of folder to save images    

listing = os.listdir(path1)    
for file in listing:
    im = Image.open(path1 + file)    
    im.resize((50,50))                % need to do some more processing here             
    im.save(path2 + file, "JPEG")
```

Is there any best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems ok with processing one after another, avoiding the load to memory.

Comment: Just FYI, the Python comment character is `#`, not `%` (LaTeX programmer?). That might save you some trouble in the future. :)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Please put a little more description in your question -- help us help you by making your question as complete as possible.

Comment: If you want it to not be a blocking call, I would create a `thread` for every image processing.

Comment: @ChristianTernus: As I mention above, I need to open images from one folder and by doing some processing need to save them in another folder. At present I am doing this by opening one image at a time, process it and then saving it into another folder. My question is whether it can be done for all images at a time rather than opening them one by one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like you want multithreading. Here's a quick rev that'll do that.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os

path1 = "some/path"
path2 = "some/other/path"

listing = os.listdir(path1)    

p = Pool(5) # process 5 images simultaneously

def process_fpath(path):
    im = Image.open(path1 + path)    
    im.resize((50,50))                # need to do some more processing here             
    im.save(os.path.join(path2,path), "JPEG")

p.map(process_fpath, listing)
```

(edit: use [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) instead of `Thread`, see that doc for more examples and information)

Answer (score 2):

You can use glob to read the images one by one

```
import glob
from PIL import Image


images=glob.glob("*.jpg")
for image in images:
    img = Image.open(image)
    img1 = img.resize(50,50)
    img1.save("newfolder\\"+image)
```

Comment: This is good, but correct syntax is `img.resize((50,50))` with the `(50,50)` as a tuple. Otherwise the second 50 gets interpreted as the `resample` argument and you'll get `PIL: ValueError: unknown resampling filter`