# How can I load a directory of PNGs into Python?

Tags: python, image, file, directory

Suppose I have an image editing script in Python that will crop and rearrange an image. However, I want to run this script on a whole directory of images. How could I load a whole directory of images into Python so that the script could loop through the images and edit each individual one?
Right now I have:

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
img = Image.open(sys.argv[0], 'r')
''' some editing stuff '''
```

Comment: A whole *file*? Well, yes, by definition, right?

Comment: Did you mean *directory*?

Comment: yeah i meant directory

Answer (score 0):

Possibly relevant:

[Open images from a folder one by one using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573809/open-images-from-a-folder-one-by-one-using-python)

It probably makes sense to load one image, do the processing, save it, then load another. But this is how you do it generally, using os.listdir.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all files into memory at once, process them individually in a loop:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
PATH = "path/to/images"
for image in os.listdir(PATH):
    if image.endswith(".png"):
        img = Image.open(image, 'r')
        ''' some editing stuff '''
```

---

What this is going to do is loop through all files in `PATH`. If the file has a `.png` extension, it will begin your image processing loop. Once your editing stuff is complete, the next file will be processed.